# jQuery attribute selector inside if statement

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to make my if statement work, but I cannot find the solution. Thanks.

```
<div class="imgContain">
    <img class="finalimg" alt="link" src="website.com/imga546.jpg">
    <img class="finalimg" alt="green" src="website.com/imga645.jpg">
    <img class="finalimg" alt="cap" src="website.com/imga6786.jpg">
    <img class="finalimg" alt="sarge" src="website.com/imga31234.jpg">
</div>
```

Pseudo-code

```
jQuery if(something = to any of my alt attributes){do...}
//altattr is equal to an attribute that may match the alt attribute
```

ex: `if('link' == $('img[class="finalimg"]').attr('alt'))`

```
 if(altattr == $('img[class="finalimg"]').attr('alt')){
        //do stuff
        }
```

I have to select the class imgContain first to make this work right?
I know that this will only work on my first element, but I'm trying to make the if statement work first.

Answer (score 1):

You're too hung up on fixing the if statement when you don't even need one.

```
$('.finalimg[alt="link"]').doSomething();
```

or

```
$('.finalimg[alt="link"]').each(function(){
    // do something with this...
    $(this).doSomething();
});
```

and to use a variable in place of "link", use string concatenation.

```
$('.finalimg[alt="' + altattr + '"]').doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/m4Lk6/

```
if(0 !=  $('img[class="finalimg"][src="website.com/imga546.jpg"]').length) {
    $('body').append('<div>I found the image!</div>');
}
```

Here i am testing for the existence of an image element that has the proper class and source. If it exists its length will be 1, if not it will be 0.

EDIT: made a change based on the fact that the selector could return a number greater than one if there were multiples of these in the page.

Comment: well, more precisely, it won't be 0 if it exists. It could be greater than one if there are multiple. little nitpicky tho

Comment: Ah - true. I was just thinking with the current set of HTML that the OP provided.

Answer (score 0):

This will loop through all images with the class `finalimg` and once it's found one matching  (in this case the last img) the `altattr` variable it will alert.

```
var altattr = 'sarge';

$("img[class='finalimg']").each( function(index, element){
    if(altattr == $(this).attr('alt')){
        alert("found");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try select the image with the specified alt attribute if there aren't any length will be zero.

```
if($('img[class="finalimg"][alt="' + altattr +  '"]').length > 0){
        //do stuff
}
```

This would be equivalent using class selector:

```
if($('img.finalimg[alt="' + altattr +  '"]').length > 0){
        //do stuff
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/_wilmer/ma8T7/)